# What to do about "is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path." error when trying to use render_to_string in a PORO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I refactored some of my code that generates a PDF into a separate class that lives in /lib. Problem is that the class depends on the `render_to_string` method from `ActionController::Base`.

The code is quite simple:

```
 class Pdf
    def pdf_content(record)
      render_to_string(
        partial: 'pdf/content.pdf.haml',
        layout: 'pdf/application.pdf.erb',
        locals: { record: record.decorate }
      )
    end

    def render_to_string(*params)
      ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(params)
    end
  end
```

When I try to call the class `Pdf.new.pdf_content(record)` I get an error: `is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.`

Thanks!

Comment: You can just use  `include ActiveModel::Model` to make it compatible.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the splat operator? what's in `record.decorate`? the problem is related to the params you are passing to the `render_to_string` method

Comment: You are right, that solved the problem. The splat operator is just to indicate that I can pass multiple params right? Am I not doing that in this method call?